# web2py: How do I add javascript to Web2py Crud form?

Tags: javascript, python, crud, web2py

Working with Web2Py. I'm trying to attach some javascript either to a field (onchange) or to the form (onsubmit), but I see absolutely no way to pass such argument to crud.create or to form.custom.widget.

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 4):

Of course there is a way. The appropriate way is to ask people on the web2py mailing list who know how to, as opposed to generic stack overflow users who will guess an incorrect answer. :-)

Anyway, assume you have:

```
db.define_table('image',
    Field('name'),
    Field('file', 'upload'))
```

You can do

```
def upload_image():
    form=crud.create(db.image)
    form.element(name='file')['_onchange']='... your js here ...'
    form.element('form')['_onsubmit']='... your js here ...'
    return dict(form=form)
```

Element takes the css3/jQuery syntax (but it is evaluated in python).

Comment: my apologies, just trying to help and I thought I was a pretty savy web2py user (I did the taskbar widget).  I wouldn't dismiss stackoverflow over mailing lists, stackoverflow is a lot more fun :)

Comment: @Mark, no apologize needed. Your answer was good. It does solve the problem effectively. I am not convinces that the controller is in fact the right place to set these attributes. @Bob, element is in the docs but the examples use other attributes, not onchange and onsubmit.

Comment: this worked for me: using form.element(_name='file') (notice the underscore in _name )

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is a way to do this directly.  One option is just to manipulate web2py generated HTML, it is just a string.  Even cleaner, in my opinion, is just to bind the event using jQuery's $(document).ready() function.

Say you have a database table (all is stolen from web2py's docs):

```
db.define_table('image',
    Field('name'),
    Field('file', 'upload'))
```

With form:

```
def upload_image():
    return dict(form=crud.create(db.image))
```

Embedded in a view (in the simplest manner):

```
{{=form}}
```

And you want to add an onblur handler to the name input field (added to the view):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#image_name").blur(function(){
      // do something with image name loses focus...
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, it might be useful for other cases.